# Non-elementary Fuchsian Group and the Invariant Measure for the Corresponding Action on the Limit Set

Tags: measure-theory, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, complex-manifolds, hyperbolic-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a **Fuchsian Group** (that means a Discrete Subgroup of $RSL_2(\mathbb{R})$) acting on the **Closed Unit Disc** $\mathbb{D}$.

Let $\Lambda (\Gamma)$ be the **Limit Set** of $\Gamma$, i.e., it is the smallest closed subest of $\mathbb{D}$ that is invariant under the action of $\Gamma$.

Is there any theorem that states that if $\Gamma$ is **Non-elementary** (that means the limit set $\Lambda (\Gamma)$ contains at least three elements) then there is no invariant measure for the action of $\Gamma$ on its Limit Set $\Lambda (\Gamma)$.

Comment: What kind of measure? In particular, what are you assuming about it's sigma-algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your definition of the limit set $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ is not quite correct. For instance, you forgot to add *nonempty*. But also, your definition does not work for elementary subgroups. The standard definition is that the limit set is the accumulation set in $\partial {\mathbb D}$ of an orbit of $\Gamma$ in the interior of ${\mathbb D}$.

Now, to your question. The answer depends on your assumptions about a measure. A measure on a set $X$ consists of choice of a sigma-algebra ${\mathcal A}\subset 2^X$ and a function $\mu: {\mathcal A}\to [0,\infty)$ satisfying axioms of a measure.

For $X=\Lambda(\Gamma)$, let's take  ${\mathcal A}\subset 2^X$ equal $\{\emptyset, X\}$ and $\mu(X)=1$, $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. This is clearly a measure and it is obviously $\Gamma$-invariant.

At the other extreme, suppose that $\mu$ is a [Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) probability measure on $X=\Lambda(\Gamma)$. Then it is a pleasant exercise in using density in $X$ of fixed points of hyperbolic elements of $\Gamma$ to see that $\mu$ cannot be $\Gamma$-invariant (if $\Gamma$ is nonelementary, of course). If you want a hint for solving this exercise, use the following property:

If $\gamma\in \Gamma$ is hyperbolic with repulsive (resp. attractive) fixed points $\lambda_-, \lambda_+$ and $J$ is an open interval in $S^1$ containing $\lambda_-$, then
$$
\bigcup_{n\ge 0} \gamma^n(J)= S^1 \setminus \{\lambda_+\}.
$$

Comment: The limit set is not necessarily non-empty.

Comment: @Neilhawking: As I said, this definition does not work for elementary groups (e.g. ones with empty limit set). For nonelementary groups, a valid description of the limit set is that it is smallest closed $\Gamma$-invariant **nonempty** subset of $S^1$. If you skip the word "nonempty" here (as you did), then the empty set is always the smallest, invariant and closed.